# Setting image src attribute not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, image

I want to get the `src` of one image and set it as another's `src` when `#btn` is pressed:

```
jQuery("#btn").live("click", function() {
    jQuery("#another_div")
        .children("img")
        .attr("src", jQuery(this).prev("img").attr("src"));
    jQuery(this)
        .prev("img")
        .attr("src","");
})
```

I have also tried:

```
jQuery(this).prev('img').removeAttr("src");
```

It works fine in Firefox, IE7-9, and Safari.

Only in Chrome, the image is not removed even when the source changes (`src=""`).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could change it to

```
jQuery(this).attr("src", "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");
```

maybe?

Comment: Hi Joseph, it seems this works when you do this. Can you explain what is this you have put for the src value? See http://jsfiddle.net/K7SBx/1/

Comment: Ok I got it. it is a base64 encoded string for a 1px by 1px transparent GIF image.

Comment: @ManjulaWeerasinge You are correct. :)   I should have explained that. XD  Sorry, I did not see your question until this morning.

Answer (score 3):

Since in my case by doing this

```
$(this).attr("src","");
```

clearing the src attribute, but, image does not vanish. Hence I just set, img tag style attribute display to none, like this

```
$(this).attr("src","").css("display", "none");
```

It will hide the image. I hope, it will temporarily work for you.

Answer (score 2):

try remove image and append it again

```
jQuery('#another_div').children("img").remove()
jQuery('#another_div').append('<img>').attr("src",jQuery(this).prev('img').attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works well with Chrome and does not seem to give any messages to console:

```
image.src = "about:blank"; // Clear source path
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#btn').live("click", function() {
    jQuery('#another_div')
        .children("img")
        .attr("src", jQuery(this).prev('img').attr("src"));
    jQuery(this)
        .prev('img').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the src first to blank

```
$(this).attr("src","");
```

then

```
$(this).removeAttr("src");
```

Comment: Warning: Do not do this. This will cause an additional server request!

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2236-empty-src-and-url-values-can-cause-duplicate-page-requests.htm

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var $image = $('.my-image-selector');
$image.removeAttr('src').replaceWith($image.clone());
```

However, be wary of any event handlers that you might have attached to the image. There's always the **withDataAndEvents** and **deepWithDataAndEvents** options for **jQuery clone**, but I haven't tested the code with them: http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents

Also, if you want to do this for multiple images, you will probably have to use something like **jQuery each**.

I posted an identical answer on a similar question: [Clear an IMG with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865689/clear-an-img-with-jquery/16236448#16236448)