# HTML/Javascript remove data from img src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an empty img in my page `<img ... src=""/>`

When an event occurs I set the img attribute to an inline png data:

`<img ... src="data:image/png;base64,..."/>`

When another event occurs I set the src to **nothing** (remove the img): `myImg.src = ""`

The problem is: The img doesn't reload when I set src to nothing. If I hide the img, wait some time and show it again it works but it's an ugly hack...

P.S: I don't want to set a default 'blank' image I need it to be really blank (src = "").

Edit:
My javascript:

```
biometria.setImage = function(png) {
    if(png)
        bioCanvas.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + png;
    else
        bioCanvas.src = '';
};
```

Edit2: Browser: Google Chrome 18.0.1025.162 Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: grab the base64 code for an transparent 1px/1px and use that, also maybe about:blank but I reckon that will show as broken in some browser as not returning an image format.

Comment: Can you share the script code that you're using?

Comment: My javascript works, it sets the src to "" but the image keep showing.

Comment: Browser: Google Chrome 18.0.1025.162 Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can't you simply hide the image when it's empty ? What the use case for the "I need it to be really blank" ?

Comment: Why add/remove the source when you can just show() or hide() the image ?

Comment: He said if he hide it wait and display again it works so I reckon he need it there empty, it could be a frame / place holder if it has a border. The transparent image would do the trick tho, but seems like he need it empty (also I believe that can show broken image icon on older IEs)

Comment: visibility: hidden when the src is blank? The img will continue to take up space, but won't be visible...what is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What's the advantage of having an image with an empty source?

Comment: It seems like the chrome devs (webkit?) make a decision on the checksum of the src attribute. They probably asked themselves "why would anyone have an image element with an empty src?" and decided "you wouldn't". Either way [All browsers but chrome work](http://jsfiddle.net/hP3K3/3/), at least for me. -- I Take that back, Safari 5.1 doesn't either.

Comment: seems to relate to an older issue where if the img src is blank the browser would still generate a request to the server...see [Empty image src can destroy your site](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/)

Comment: I chose the visibility:hidden path it's not perfect but it works for me. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: Related post with a fix: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8425817/104380

Comment: @GillesC, post your comment as an answer to upvote it ☺ (I used your base64 solution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, a image tag is required to have a src attribute AND it is supposed to NOT be empty.  However, the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) isn't clear on how to handle the cases when the src attribute is empty. As a result, every browser is handling this situation slightly differently.

There are actually quite a few problems that can arise from this lack in specification, yours is just one of them.  A more detailed look at this issue can be found [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/).

As others have pointed out, it is much more preferable to hide/show the image through CSS (either visibility:none if you want to keep the space occupied, or display:none if you want the image to completely disappear).  Alternatively, you can simply remove the complete image tag using JS and create a new image when you want to insert it back.

Comment: Thanks, the visibility:hidden did the job even tough it doesn't show the img outline (I can live with that).

Comment: @islon Note that if you set an img to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` and it does have a valid src, it still gets downloaded!

Answer (score 15):

I handle this issue by blow code and work for me:

```
document.getElementById('tst').removeAttribute('src');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you replace the image with a new one. In jQuery you could do something like :

```
$('#yourImage').replaceWith('&lt;img src="" id="yourImage" /&gt;');
```