# Clear an IMG with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm trying to remove the loaded image from a `<img>` element, but clearing or removing the src doesn't do it. What to do?

**HTML:**

```
<img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('img').attr('src', ''); // Clear the src
$('img').removeAttr('src');​ // Remove the src
```

Image remains...

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6x9NZ/

Comment: What do you mean by clearing the img ? You want to remove the img element from the DOM ?

Comment: no- clear the loaded image from the img element

Comment: Well, it does not remain in every brother. AND can you give an example for what can of behavior you need to just clear the src attribute without removing the img element from the DOM ?

Comment: I guess he was trying to retain the `img` node but not the image data. This maybe useful to free memory when the images are out of view.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You would have to either [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the `<img>` element entirely or replace it with a different image (which could be a transparent gif).

Comment: Alternately you could change the src to a 1x1 pixel: `$('img').attr('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==');`

Comment: @davidsleeps — It's just an example of what I said in this answer.

Comment: @Quentin apologies, I can see that now...but because it doesn't involve the existence of another image, it feels a bit different.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
var $image = $('.my-image-selector');
$image.removeAttr('src').replaceWith($image.clone());
```

However, be wary of any event handlers that you might have attached to the image. There's always the **withDataAndEvents** and **deepWithDataAndEvents** options for **jQuery clone**, but I haven't tested the code with them: http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents

Also, if you want to do this for multiple images, you will probably have to use something like **jQuery each**.

I posted an identical answer on a similar question: [Setting image src attribute not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425817/setting-image-src-attribute-not-working-in-chrome/16236569#16236569)

Answer (score 11):

You can do this. First assign the image an ID

```
<img id='image_id' src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
```

And then remove the source attribute.

```
jQuery('#image_id').removeAttr('src')
jQuery('#image_id').show();
```

Answer (score 5):

what about simply hiding an element:

```
$('img').hide();
```

You cannot remove an image from  a tag. When you use jQuery, bear in mind that you do not deal with tags, you manupulate with DOM elements. Therefore, your tag  in terms of jquery  is not a tag, it is an object, a DOM element. And this is element is not a  tag, IT IS an element that represents an image in DOM. So if you want to hide an image, you must hide the element.

Comment: you can even hide an element, big deal!! Just have and id to your img tag and then do `$('#myImageID').hide()`.

Comment: If you want to show it again use `show()` on the element

Answer (score 3):

Remove the node using

```
$("img").remove()
```

or simply hide the image using

```
$("img").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to replace image with another. i mean instead of cleaning the src, set a fake value like .attr('src','notting');
it'll load no image and the cached version of old image will be gone

Comment: is it important that after pageload you get 404? you can replace it whit an existing empty image.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.Replacing the image attribute src within div 'custom_preview_image' to blank

```
field = jQuery(this).closest('td').find('.custom_repeatable li:last').clone(true); field.find('.custom_preview_image').removeAttr('src').end();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the element to take up the space, but being invisible, hide it with css. Give your image a class or id and hide it like:

```
<img id='hide' src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>

$('#hide').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of showing broken image while setting `"src"` to `"#"`, There is a workaround, so you can set `alt` attribute to the desired text:

```
 $('#thumbnialPreviewImage').attr('src', '#');
 $('#thumbnialPreviewImage').attr('alt', 'Please Select Image');
```