# Picture delete/remove code syntax using cshtml (base64 image)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

How can I put a delete icon to remove a base64 image record from database record? I've attached CSHTML section of image uploader and the Javascript for the uploader. I've also attached screenshot of the database record. Btw, I'm using C# MVC. Thank you in advance for the help.

**The page**
[image: Screenshot of the page]

**Database record**
[image: Database record screenshot]

```js
function Picture_Upload(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#Form_Account #PICTURE').val(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        $("#lable_file").html($(input).val().split("\\").splice(-1, 1)[0] || '@Language_List.Where(x => x.KEYWORD == "No_File_Chosen").First().VALUE');
    }
}
```

```cshtml
<div class="col-lg-4 well well-sm">

  Account Picture
  <br /> @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PICTURE)) {
  <img src='@Model.PICTURE' style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%" /> } else {
  <img src="~/img/Logo_Blank.png" style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;" /> }

  <br /><br />

  <div class="Toggle_Form_Account" style="display:none; width:100%">
    @*<input id="file_upload" type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="Picture_Upload(this);" />*@
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('file_upload').click()">@Language_List.Where(x => x.KEYWORD == "Choose_File").First().VALUE</button> <label for="file_upload" id="lable_file" style="font-weight: normal !important;">@Language_List.Where(x => x.KEYWORD == "No_File_Chosen").First().VALUE</label>
    <input id="file_upload" type="file" style="display:none" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="Picture_Upload(this);" />
  </div>
```

Comment: First you need `<button type="button" ...>` and assign it with an ID, then you may call controller action from that button to delete stored image from DB based from parameter you're using (e.g. record ID).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thank you for that option. But i want also the button to make image disappear as on the button click

Comment: Probably this jQuery trick may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865689/clear-an-img-with-jquery. However it depends on how you transmit the data as parameter(s) to controller action (using normal form submit or AJAX).

Comment: Alright thanks. Can i apply this to my method because I’m using the photo uploader and save button after a user uploaded it? Same goes to deleting it.