# How to set image src to empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting image src attribute not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425817/setting-image-src-attribute-not-working-in-chrome)

When user clicks on "remove" link I need to set the `src` attribute of an image to empty. When I do it using

```
$('#img').prop('src', null);
```

`src` is not empty but points to current url

if I remove `src` using

```
$('#img').removeProp('src');
```

never let me to assign it back in the future

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425853/561731)

Comment: An empty string can actually be a valid src for an image, technically speaking it is not "removing" the src. Same as `#`, it would use the current URL plus the hash. Real example: http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/squirrel/ You would end up sending a request to the current URL. I would suggest using another approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Vnj53/)**

```
$('#img').attr('src', '');
```

As you have id selector. Using the native javascript method document.getElementById will give you more performance benefit. Also you may need to set `#` as `src` instead of `empty` string.

```
document.getElementById('img').src = "#";
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Still pointing to current url instead of having an empty value.

Comment: I have added live demo in my answer, check if it works

Comment: @Adil [this does not work with a real image](http://jsfiddle.net/Vnj53/1/)

Comment: It's a Chrome issue apparently.

Comment: This works from javascript point of view, for now it's enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: this now shows a broken image

Comment: using `#` as `src` makes an extra request to current HTML page to load the image from there. this is a bad behavior

Answer (score 6):

I'd just access the underlaying `<img>` node and set the value of `src` to an *empty string*.

```
$('#img')[ 0 ].src = '#';
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P4pRu/

---

Update: It seems like *Chrome* is not satisfied when we just pass in an *empty string*. Firefox still shows the expected behavior (I'm pretty sure that this also worked in Chrome a couple of weeks/versions ago).

However, passing over a `#` for instance, works fine.

---

Update 2:

Even `imgNode.removeAttribute('src');` does no longer remove the visual representation of an image anymore in Chrome (interesting...).

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Still pointing to current url instead of having an empty value.

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool: indeed. Wierd behavior which to me seems, "new". However, it works if you pass in a `#` for instance.

Comment: An empty string can actually be a valid src for an image, technically speaking it is not "removing" the src. Same as `#`, it would use the current URL plus the hash. Real example: http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/squirrel/ You would end up sending a request to the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute 'src' isn't really a property, it is an attribute. Think of properties as things that can be set with booleans or lists and attributes as things that are much more dynamic.

```
$('#img').attr('src', '');
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Test your answer, it doesn't work (although your notes are correct).

Comment: Yes, it does. Just tested in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aAfvx/1/

Comment: Looks like it's a Chrome issue, try it in Chrome.